# Count number of sequence (not duplicated)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I actually have a multifasta file such this:

```
>seqA_0042_0035
AGGACCATGA
>seqB_0035_0042
ATGGATGGAGGAGATG
>seqC_0042_0035
AGGATGGAGGATAG
>seqA_0042_0035
ATGGAGAGAG
>seqD_0042_0035
ATTGGGAA
>seqC_0035_0042
ATGGGAGAGAAGA
>seqA_0042_0035
```

And I simply would like to count how many sequences (with ID name) I have BUT only count once if I have a seqA for exemple, even if it appears twice, I want to keep juste once.
The _number_number does not matter, they change all the time.

For this exemple I would have as output: number of sequence: 4

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a hash set that holds the labels, scan through the file, add each label to the hash set:

```
set_of_labels = set()

with open("path/to/my_multi_FASTA_file") as f:
  for line in f:
    if line.startswith('>seq'):
      label = line[4:].split('_')[0]
      set_of_labels.add(label)

print(f"Number of distinct labels: {len(set_of_labels)}")
```

Output:

```
Number of distinct labels: 4
```

The duplicates are removed automatically, because the set always holds only one copy of each element.

I've dropped the `>seq`-part and the numbers from the `>seqX_Y_Z`-labels, so I keep only `X`. If you want something else, adjust the selection of substring in `label = ....` accordingly.

Comment: A set will not preserve the order of insert prior to Python 3.7 which would produce a garbled up sequence.

Comment: @zwer to quote the question: *" I simply would like to count how many sequences"*, so I assume that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi think I did not explain it well,  I updated my post to explain it better.

Comment: @Benjamin I think my posting should also answer the latest edition of the question.

Comment: Hi got :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Get_busco_blast.py", line 21, in <module>
    print("Number of distinct labels: " + len(set_of_labels))
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: @Benjamin cast length to `str` using `str(..)`.

Comment: @Benjamin Hoppla! Sry, forgot to convert the int to string. Updated. You could also try something like `print(f"Num sequences: {len(set_of_labels)}")`.

Comment: Thanks you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If the file content is same as you specified, this could solve your query:

```
lst = []

with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>seq') and line[4] not in lst:
            lst.append(line[4])

print(lst)
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

print(len(lst))
# 4
```

Comment: Because of list, this takes quadratic time. If you have a few millions sequence names, of which a few hundred are duplicates, the performance could become pretty bad pretty quickly.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin ofcourse using `set` is better except issues with the order. I agree, just didn't catch up on that. This was the first thought of mine. Didn't work my head lot on that side of the problem. I upvoted you. :)

Comment: I changed my exemple to explain better, I think I did not explain it well

Comment: Thanks you for your help